# how to remove focus from overlay windows service on start it?

Tags: android, android-service

I have a Overlay windows service and a `EditText` in it. once I start this service to show overlay window, back button not work in any activity until I touch on screen to remove focus on overlay window. how to remove this focus after starting?

my service class is:

```
    public class MyWindowServices extends Service {

  private WindowManager              mWindowManager;
  private WindowManager.LayoutParams windowsParams;
  private View                       mView;

  private int height;

  @Override
  public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
  }

  @Override
  public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();

  }

  @Override
  public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    mView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.my_service_layout, null);

    mWindowManager = (WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE);

    moveView();

    return Service.START_STICKY;
  }

  private void moveView() {
    DisplayMetrics metrics = getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
    height = metrics.heightPixels;

    windowsParams = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
      WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
      WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,

      (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT <= 25) ? WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_PHONE : WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_APPLICATION_OVERLAY
      ,WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL
        | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_WATCH_OUTSIDE_TOUCH,
      PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);


    windowsParams.gravity = Gravity.TOP | Gravity.LEFT;
    windowsParams.y = height / 9;
    windowsParams.x = 0;
    //TODO runtime permission is needed
    mWindowManager.addView(mView, windowsParams);

    mView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
      private int initialX;
      private int initialY;
      private float initialTouchX;
      private float initialTouchY;

      long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

      @Override
      public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        if (System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime <= 300) {
          return false;
        }

        switch (event.getAction()) {
          case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            initialX = windowsParams.x;
            initialY = windowsParams.y;
            initialTouchX = event.getRawX();
            initialTouchY = event.getRawY();
            break;
          case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            windowsParams.x = initialX + (int) (event.getRawX() - initialTouchX);
            windowsParams.y = initialY + (int) (event.getRawY() - initialTouchY);
            mWindowManager.updateViewLayout(mView, windowsParams);
            break;
        }
        return false;
      }
    });
  }


  @Override
  public void onDestroy() {

    if (mView != null) {
      mWindowManager.removeView(mView);
    }

    super.onDestroy();
  }

}
```

consider this section:

```
windowsParams = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
  WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
  WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
  (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT <= 25) ? WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_PHONE : WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_APPLICATION_OVERLAY
  ,WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL
    | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_WATCH_OUTSIDE_TOUCH,
  PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);
```

if I using `WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE` insted of `WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL` my problem solved but in this case keyboard not showing on touch `EditText`

Answer (score 2):

I found solution:
changed my code to:

```
     @Override
      public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

        ...

        removeFocus();

        return Service.START_STICKY;
      }

    mView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

         ...

          @Override
          public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            ...


 if (isViewInBounds(mView, (int) (event.getRawX()), (int) (event.getRawY()))) {
      receiveFocus();
    } else {
      removeFocus();
    }

            ...

          }
        });



     private boolean wasInFocus = true;

      private boolean isViewInBounds(View view, int x, int y) {
        Rect  outRect  = new Rect();
        int[] location = new int[2];
        view.getDrawingRect(outRect);
        view.getLocationOnScreen(location);
        outRect.offset(location[0], location[1]);
        return outRect.contains(x, y);
      }

      private void receiveFocus() {
        if (!wasInFocus) {
          windowsParams.flags = WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_WATCH_OUTSIDE_TOUCH;
          mWindowManager.updateViewLayout(mView, windowsParams);
          wasInFocus = true;
        }
      }

      private void removeFocus() {
        if (wasInFocus) {
          windowsParams.flags = WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_WATCH_OUTSIDE_TOUCH;
          mWindowManager.updateViewLayout(mView, windowsParams);
          wasInFocus = false;
        }
      }
```